# Exception handling execution flow

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code.

When customer does not exist it executes Throw Number 1.

Execution continues and gets to Throw Number 2.

So the displayed message ends up being the one from Throw Number 2.

But I don't want that to happen.

When execution gets to Throw Number 1, it should stop there and never get to Throw Number 2 so that the message from Throw Number 1 is the one displayed.

How to do that?

```
public void updateCustomerName(int customerId, String name){
        
    try {   
        //code to find customer by id here          
            
        if(customerExists.isEmpty() == false) {             
            //code to update customer name here             
        }
        else {
            //THROW NUMBER 1
            throw new CustomerAPICustomException("Invalid customer id : " + customerId); 
        }           
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        //THROW NUMBER 2
        throw new CustomerAPICustomException("Customer update error.");
    }
}
```

Comment: CustomerAPICustomException inherits from Exception class so it is catched  from the catch block that you have. Maybe you do not want to catch so general exceptions. So you can either remove or change the try/catch block.

Comment: @PavMits I'd like to catch the specific exception (invalid customer Id) and also generic exceptions for the other exception scenarios. You mentioned changing the catch block. Any suggestion on the change to be made?

Comment: I think you need something like the answer bellow to make it more clean and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public void updateCustomerName(int customerId, String name){
        if(customerExists.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomerAPICustomException("Invalid customer id : " + customerId);
        }
        try{
            //customer update 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            //THROW NUMBER 2
            throw new CustomerAPICustomException("Customer update error.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good solution. It worked. The only issue is that I would need two different try catch block for the general exception. The one you showed in your example plus one at the top for the code that searches the user in the db. Anyway, the functionality works. Answer accepted. Thank you.